Linearity of Integration of Nonnegative Simple Function on General Measure

Definition: Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\psi$ a nonnegative simple function on $X$. Define the integral of $\psi$ over $X$, $\int_{X}\psi~ d\mu$, as follows: if $\psi=0$ on $X$, define $\int_E\psi ~d\mu=0$. Otherwise, let $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$ be positive values taken by $\psi$ on $X$ and, for $1\leq k\leq n$, define $E_k=\{x\in X: \psi(x)=c_k\}$. Define
$$\displaystyle\int_X \psi ~d\mu=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k\cdot \mu(E_k)$$
using the convention that the right-hand side is $\infty$ if, for some $k$, $\mu(E_k)=\infty$. For a measurable, subset $E$ of $X$, the integral of $\psi$ over $E$ with respect to $\mu$ is defined to be $\int_X \psi \cdot \chi _E d\mu$ and denoted by $\int_E\psi d\mu$.


Proposition: Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\varphi$ and $\psi$ nonnegative simple function on $X$. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers, then
$$\displaystyle \int_X[\alpha\cdot \psi+\beta \varphi]~d\mu=\alpha\cdot\int_X\psi ~d\mu+\beta\cdot \int_X\varphi~ d\mu$$

So I have a proof, can anyone check if this is correct?
Proof:
Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\psi$ and $\varphi$ be nonnegative simple functions on $X$. Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers.
Since $\psi$ and $\varphi$ take only a finite number of values of $X$, we may choose a finite disjoint collection $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that
$$\bigcup _{i=1}^nE_i=X, ~~~~\psi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\chi _{E_i}(x) ~\text{and} ~\varphi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i\chi_{E_i}(x).$$
where $a_i\geq 0$ and $b_i\geq 0$, for all $i=1,2,...,n$. Now,
$$\alpha \psi(x) +\beta \varphi(x)=\alpha\sum_{i=1}^na_i\chi_{E_i}(x)+\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}  b_i \chi_{E_i}(x)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha a_i+\beta b_i)\chi_{E_i}(x)$$
where $\alpha a_i+\beta b_i\geq 0$. Thus, $\alpha \psi(x) +\beta \varphi(x)$ is also a nonnegative simple function on $X$.
Case 1: Either $\psi$ or $\varphi$ is positive on a set of infinite measure.
Without loss of generality, let $\psi$ be positive on $X$ and $\mu(X)=\infty$. That means for all $x\in X$, $\psi(x)=a_i>0, $ for all $i=1,...,n$. Hence in this case, $\alpha a_i+\beta b_i>0$ for all $i=1,2,...,n$. So that
$$\int_X [\alpha \psi +\beta \varphi]=\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha a_i+\beta b_i)\mu(E_i)$$
By countable additivity, $\infty=\mu(X)=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(E_i)$, implying that for some $j=1,2,...,n$, $\mu(E_j)=\infty$. Hence,
$$\int_X [\alpha \psi +\beta \varphi]=\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha a_i+\beta b_i)\mu(E_i)=\infty$$
Also, $\alpha \psi=\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\chi _{E_i}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha a_i\chi _{E_i}$ where $\alpha a_i>0$ for all $i$. Hence,
$$\int_X \alpha \psi +\int_X \beta \varphi= \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha a_i \mu(E_i)+ \int_X \beta \varphi$$
$$=\infty +\int_X \beta \varphi$$
$$=\infty.$$
Thus, $\displaystyle \int_X[\alpha \psi+\beta \varphi]~d\mu=\alpha\cdot\int_X\psi ~d\mu+\beta\cdot \int_X\varphi~ d\mu$.
Case 2:$\psi$ and $\phi$ vanish outside a set of finite measure.
That is, $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $\psi(x)\geq 0$, $\varphi(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in X$. Hence $\mu(E_i)<\infty$, $a_i\geq 0$, $b_i\geq 0$ and $\alpha a_i+\beta b_i\geq 0$ for all $i=1,...,n$ so that
$$\int_X[\alpha \psi+\beta \varphi]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha a_i+\beta b_i)\mu(E_i);~~~~~~~~(1)$$
$$\int_X\psi=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mu(E_i);~~~~~~~~~(2)$$
$$\int_X\varphi=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\mu(E_i)~~~~~~~~~~(3)$$
since the terms in (1), (2) and (3) where $\alpha a_i+\beta b_i=0$, $a_i=0$ and $b_i=0$, respectively are just equal to $0$. Thus,
$$\int_X[\alpha \psi+\beta \varphi]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha a_i+\beta b_i)\mu(E_i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha a_i \mu(E_i)+\sum_{i=1}^n \beta b_i\mu(E_i)$$
$$=\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n  a_i \mu(E_i)+\beta\sum_{i=1}^n  b_i\mu(E_i)$$
$$=\alpha \int_X \psi +\beta\int_X \varphi.~~~~~~~~~~~~◼ $$
